# PostgreSQL get disk free space with COPY FROM PROGRAM

Tags: postgresql, cmd, diskspace

Since version 9.3 it is possible to import into a table the output of a commandline.
I'm using windows, and I would like to import in a (temporary) table the output of

```
wmic logicaldisk get size, freespace, caption

Caption  FreeSpace     Size
C:       7454072832    118087389184
D:       151787872256  484033048576
E:
F:       110551040     625094656
G:       136850108416  481803997184
V:       272621289472  990730260480
X:       272621289472  990730260480
Y:       272621289472  990730260480
```

I tryed the query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _disks(row text);
TRUNCATE TABLE _disks;
COPY _disks FROM PROGRAM 'wmic logicaldisk get size, freespace, caption' ESCAPE '\\' CSV;
SELECT * FROM _disks;

ERROR: COPY escape must be a single one-byte character
```

then i tryed

```
COPY _disks FROM PROGRAM 'wmic logicaldisk get size, freespace, caption' ESCAPE '\' CSV;

ERROR: unquoted newline found in data
```

then again

```
COPY _disks FROM PROGRAM 'wmic logicaldisk get size, freespace, caption';

ERROR: unquoted newline found in data
```

I tried other different solution, but I'm stuck.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

maybe something like this could get me close, but not enough

```
COPY _disks FROM PROGRAM 'for /f "tokens=*" %F in (''wmic logicaldisk get size^, freespace^, caption'') do @echo %F';
```

I think that there is a way to modify the EOL, and probably pass through this pattern, but I miss something...

Answer (score 1):

You have to state that the string value needs to be escaped by adding `E` right before it. In your case if you only pass `'\\'` it will be interpreted as two characters, which is not allowed in this function. Check this out:

```
SELECT E'\\', '\\';

 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 \        | \\
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: good advice, but the error reported is always `unquoted newline found in data`

Comment: @tmx976 It seems your file has no `CR-LF`. Is it possible to pre-process it before import? I suspect it has only a `\r` in the end of the line instead of `\r\n`

Comment: it is a command line output, maybe some other command line tool could do the job, but i dont know.. I will investigate

Comment: `crlf` in windows can be quite annoying. Let us know here how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get a CSV file. There are ways to write into a database, but I assume there are many ways to import a CSV file already well known.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
    Select-Object -Property DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' |
    Out-File -FilePath 'ld.txt' -Encoding ascii
```

This can be used in a cmd.exe .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |" ^
        "Select-Object -Property DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size |" ^
        "ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' |" ^
        "Out-File -FilePath 'ld.txt' -Encoding ascii"
```